# Maximum number of processes in SPIN model

Tags: spin, promela

I created multiple processed which in turn are spawning other processes. Thus SPIN model keeps printing "Too many processes (Max 255)". However, it is still giving me the end output. If it cannot handle more than 255 processes how does it still manage to give me the final output?

Comment: Where is your code? If code has good error handling for process management, you may be able to result. It all depends the code.

Answer (score 2):

The output 'Too many processes' is just a warning.  Spin simply ignores the additional spawns and continues executing the existing processes.  Apparently your Spin model does not depend on the 'in turn' spawning.